# My For loop won't delete the cells that match the nested If requirements

Tags: excel, vba

I finally got this to work and I am happier for it but I need to take it to the next level for chart building. As you can see it progresses through the columns and rows and clears a pair of cells. When I try to make a chart of the full row it comes up with gaps in it because of the cleared cells. There is a "with" statement going on here but its just a reference to another sheet since the code is being executed from a different sheet; pushing as opposed to pulling.

```
LCcfd = .Standard Last Column code. The cfd referst to the abv. of a sheet.
Lrcfd = .Standard Last Row code. The cfd refers to the abv. of a sheet. 

For x = 2 to LRcfd Step 2
    CF = 2
    For Each cel in .Range(.Cells(x, 2), .Cells(x, LCcfd))
        If cel = 0 Or cel = "0" Then
            cel.Clear
            .Cells(x - 1, CF).Clear
        End If
        CF = CF + 1
    Next
Next
```

To take it to the next level I tried to change the `.Clear` to `.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft` and it is NOT working as expected at all. I figured this was because it is progressing in the columns from left to right. I attempted to write the code so it goes through Each backwards but it will not accept a `Step -1`. So, I don't know how to do that.

What can I do to this code to make it step backwards through the rows? Or:

What can you recommend I change the code to, to make this happen?

Comment: where is "x" utilized?

Comment: Where's your `With` statement? Also, you don't need the `Else` statement. Just end the `If` statement after `.Clear`, then do the `CF = CF + 1`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "x"; fixed that. The PC was supposed to be replaced by the "x."
Thank you @BruceWayne for clearing the useless Else statement. When a problem causes me a lot of grief I seem to do worse coding.

Comment: Seems like you ignored Cyril's comment bellow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will try to give an example, though I don't know your exact criteria for your range (variables which aren't displayed in your posted code)

```
dim r as long, c as long 
for r = 10 to 1 step -1
    for c = 10 to 1 step -1
        if cells(r,c).value = 0 or cells(r,c).value = "0" then cells(r,c).delete shift:=xltoleft
    next c 
next r
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyril. I like the way you contstructed the nested For and use of "r" and "c" for variables; mine were confusing me sometimes and this made it so much simplier. I did have to modify it slightly but going off of what you had you gave me the right answer. All I really needed was the "shift:=xlToLeft" and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Speaking of which. What is the difference, if any, between: Shift:=xlShiftToLeft and Shift:=xlToLeft? I appear to have gotten very different answers.

Comment: I do not know about the difference between those; i have never used xlshifttoleft when i've coded in VBA for Excel.  if that answers your question, please mark as answered (check mark on the left of the post).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to write the evaluated content of the datasource to another worksheet (or Range) dedicated to serving your chart.  This avoids the cell delete/shift manipulations and keeps yours source data intact - probably making debugging easier.

```
Sub GenerateChartDataFromSource()
    Dim sourceWksht As Worksheet
    Set sourceWksht = Application.Worksheets("Source")

    Dim chartWksht As Worksheet
    Set chartWksht = Application.Worksheets("ChartSource")


    Dim sourceRow As Long, sourceColumn As Long
    Dim chartSourceColumn As Long

    Dim sourceContent As Variant

    Dim sourceRowStart As Long, sourceRowEnd As Long
    sourceRowStart = 1
    sourceRowEnd = 10

    Dim sourceColumnStart As Long, sourceColumnEnd As Long
    sourceColumnStart = 1
    sourceColumnEnd = 10

    For sourceRow = sourceRowStart To sourceRowEnd
        chartSourceColumn = sourceColumnStart
        For sourceColumn = sourceColumnStart To sourceColumnEnd
            sourceContent = sourceWksht.Cells(sourceRow, sourceColumn).value
            If sourceContent <> 0 Or sourceContent <> "0" Then
                chartWksht.Cells(sourceRow, chartSourceColumn) = sourceContent
                chartSourceColumn = chartSourceColumn + 1
            End If
        Next sourceColumn
    Next sourceRow
End Sub
```